# How do I create a foreign constant in PureScript?

Tags: javascript, string, constants, purescript

I'm trying to create a foreign constant in PureScript but it doesn't seem to call the function.

I have in PureScript:

```hs
module Test where

foreign import test :: String

foreign import test2 :: String -> String
```

and in JavaScript:

```js
"use strict";

// module Test

exports.test = function() {
    return "A";
};

exports.test2 = function(x) {
    return x;
};
```

But it doesn't call the foreign function:

```
> import Prelude
> :t test
Prim.String
> :t test2
Prim.String -> Prim.String
> test
undefined

> test2 "test"
"test"
> test ++ "A"
"function () {\n    return \"A\";\n}A"
```

Is it possible to create a foreign constant? Or are all functions expected to have at least one parameter? I'm using:

```
$ pulp psci --version
0.7.0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the extra functions. The runtime representation of `String` is just a string!

```
"use strict";

// module Test

exports.test = "A";
```

`test2` is correct, however. The runtime representation of `->` is a one-argument Javascript function, as you already have.

Comment: Thanks! I was expecting a function without parameters to be a constant but this makes sense.